# Change logs translation of Wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, translation

Can we translate change logs section of a plugin's readme.txt on https://translate.wordpress.org?

As Wordpress uses [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/) for it's plugins' repositories, and this is emphasized  that we should commit all things together but not minor changes, so we need to know if a specific section of a readme.txt (as minor change) is translatable or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that everything in a readme.txt is translatable.
for example: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/dev-readme/fa/default